# How to add hyperlinks into Word docx using open XML?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, openxml

I am having a trouble adding hyperlinks to my word document. I don't know how to do it. I would like to make a link in a word document from my C# code using open xml. Is ther a different solution using only href or sth similar? There is a HyperLink class on the net from Open XML but how to use it?

Comment: Maybe this will help http://blogs.catapultsystems.com/jdunagan/archive/2011/04/21/add-hyperlinks-to-a-word-document-with-open-xml.aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this

```
using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open("", true))
{
    doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.AppendChild(
        new Paragraph(
            new Hyperlink(new Run(new Text("Click here")))
            {
                 Anchor = "Description",
                 DocLocation = "location",
             }
        )
    );

    doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();

}
```

Comment: I will try this and let you know. Thanks